# jQuery "on" with "hover" being executed on mouse out

Tags: jquery

I have a function below that is executed on hover, but on mouse out, it also executes again.  Any reason why this would do that?

```
  $(element).on('hover', '.item', function () {})
```

Comment: Because when you pass only one function, it is considered the In and Out handler. Hover also allows you to pass separate in a and out functions: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's `hover` event is designed for notification upon both begin and end of the hover.  When used the way you are using it, it calls your event handler for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can either check `event.type` in the handler to see which event is firing when the event fires or you can switch to using `$(element).hover(fn1, fn2)` and pass both functions.

From the [jQuery doc for .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single
>   event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine
>   event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave.
>   Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method,
>   which accepts one or two functions.

So, basically, you shouldn't be using `$(element).on('hover', ...);`  Instead, use `.hover()` and pass both event handlers or pass a single event handler and check `event.type`.

Comment: But I want to take advantage of the event delegation of the .on

Comment: @MikeFlynn - hover doesn't work with delegation because it isn't a real event that propagates (it's something jQuery made up).  You can use mouseenter and mouseleave with delegation if you want.  Plus, did you have the delegated form of `.on()` in your question when you first posted it?  I didn't see it there then.

Comment: I know I was just wondering on that part,  mouseenter is working right now I will work with what you mentioned.